# Function flow: why does this function return 20

Tags: r, function, scoping

Suppose I have a function called `l`:

```
l <- function(x) x + 1
```

then define another function, `m`, but within `m`, redefine `l`:

```
m <- function() {
       l <- function(x) x*2
       l(10)
}
m()
```

Why does `m` return `x*2`, and not `x+1`?

Comment: In the given example you are calling function m() and with in function m() you are calling function l() R will first search in the function environment and will search the environment where it was called so there for second function is choosed

Comment: Before calling a function the function has to be defined that's why function is called after function definition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're not sure what's going on, it can be helpful to add some print statements. Let's add a few print statements to your code -- one before `m` is called, two inside the `m` function, and one after `m` is called:

```
l <- function(x) x + 1
m <- function() {
  print(l)
  l <- function(x) x * 2
  print(l)
  l(10)
}
print(l)
# function(x) x + 1
m()
# function(x) x + 1
# function(x) x * 2
# <environment: 0x7f8da5ac3b58>
# [1] 20
print(l)
# function(x) x + 1
```

Before `m` is called and at the top of `m`, `l` is defined as a function that returns `x+1`. However, within `m` you change `l` to be a new function, one that returns `x*2`, as indicated by the second print statement in that function. As a result, calling `l(10)` returns 20. Finally once you leave that function you are back to the original `l` definition (`x+1`) because the `x*2` version was only defined for the function. The concept of a function only being defined locally is called [name masking](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html).

Comment: thanks so much...also could u tl me wat dis environment :0x7f8... output is all about, i ws trying the same print and debug thing and it kept popping up instead of the value?

Comment: @VinayakBakshi this indicates that the function is defined within `m` instead of in the global environment. If you're interested in more details about environments in R, there are [excellent resources available](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html).